# How to take a screenshot of login screen?

Tags: 11.10, login-screen, lightdm, screenshot, unity-greeter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I take a screenshot of the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43458/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-login-screen)

I want to make a screenshot of my Login Screen on Ubuntu 11.10. So far, no method I read here has worked out for me. So I'm asking it here now. How can I accomplish this without creating a VM to screencap it outside the box?

Comment: Duplication of http://askubuntu.com/q/43458/22263

Comment: It would be good to know which method you have already tried and which didn't work for you for us to better guide you.