# capture login screen-not sucssecful

Tags: 12.04, login-screen, screenshot, xserver, capture

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 . If more information is needed, please tell me.
I Tried some guides to cature my login screen:

[How can I take a screenshot of the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43458/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-login-screen)

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-your-login-screen

I tried the first one, but after running:

```
$ sudo bash /tmp/shot.sh >/tmp/shot.xwd
```

I'm getting this:

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified    
xwd unable to open display ':0'
```

and i'm getting an xwd file in my tmp folder.
running the other commands giving errors.

tried the second one, after running:

```
chvt 8; sleep 5; XAUTHORITY=/var/gdm/:0.Xauth DISPLAY=:0.0 import -window root /tmp/gdm-login-shot.png
```

I got:

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
import: unable to open X server ':0.0' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/366
```

Many Thanks for helping (:

EDIT to vine_user:
here the output from the terminal-I cacked it from within the system while I'm looged in:

```
ubuntu@PrecisePangolin:~$ echo 'sleep 5; DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/$DISPLAYDISPLAY xwd -root' > /tmp/shot.sh
ubuntu@PrecisePangolin:~$ sudo bash /tmp/shot.sh >/tmp/shot.xwd
bash: /tmp/shot.xwd: Permission denied
ubuntu@PrecisePangolin:~$ sudo su
root@PrecisePangolin:/home/ubuntu#  sudo bash /tmp/shot.sh >/tmp/shot.xwd
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
xwd:  unable to open display ':0'
root@PrecisePangolin:/home/ubuntu#
```

EDIT 2!: HERE IT IS!:
[image]

just uploading-this uploadong site is better than other iuset to use (: :
[image]

Comment: Sorry, `/var/run/lightdm/root/$DISPLAYDISPLAY` was my misleading.Replace to `/var/run/lightdm/root/$DISPLAY`.

Comment: Never be sorry for helping (: you're helping me a lot! I'm going to try your solution, Thanks!

Comment: And It's Working! Thanks SO MUCH! YOU Made My Day! Thanks! I'm Editing and I'll put my picture (:                                                                another thing, except that the display manager is different in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Have I done another things unright earlier? Could you please teach me a bit about my mistake and way it's wrong? It will help me in the future (: Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step1:**

Make **/tmp/shot.sh** using this command:

```
echo 'sleep 20; DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/$DISPLAY xwd -root' > /tmp/shot.sh
```

You may change the seconds of `sleep` suitably.

**Step2:**

Login to the text mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

**Step3:**

Execute this command;

```
 sudo bash /tmp/shot.sh >/tmp/shot.xwd
```

**Step4:**

Return to the GUI mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

**Step5:**

Logout by normal way. While you can see login screen, wait for some seconds.

**Step6:**

Login by normal way. And execute this command in terminal;

```
convert /tmp/shot.xwd /tmp/shot.png
```

(you need to install `imagemagick`, if you don't have installed it yet)

So, you can check the picture using this command;

```
eog /tmp/shot.png
```

Reference: http://ptspts.blogspot.jp/2010/02/how-to-create-screen-shot-of-gdm-login.html

In 12.04, it differs in using **lightdm**.

Comment: you mean:                                                         $ sudo bash sleep 20; DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/$DISPLAY xwd -root >/tmp/shot.xwd ?

Comment: I edited and put the output.

Comment: OK, I will rewrite in detail, please wait a moment.

Comment: ok, I'm waiting for your new comment/answer. Thanks you for helping.

Comment: I may be loggedout fron the site untill tomorrw night. it's just i have to go. I'll check your good answer then.  Thanks again, you're great (:

Answer (score 3):

The answer by vine_user gave me a Black image so I modified it as below and got it correctly

1. Make /tmp/shot.sh with the command `echo 'chvt 7; sleep 10; DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/$DISPLAY xwd -root' > /tmp/shot.sh`
2. Logout and login to text mode (*Ctrl+Alt+F1*)
3. Execute `sudo bash /tmp/shot.sh >/tmp/shot.xwd`
4. Return to GUI mode by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7 (sometimes it is Ctrl+Alt+F8 - if it is your case then modify the fisrt command by replacing chvt 7 with chvt 8
5. Use the command `convert /tmp/shot.xwd ~/Desktop/shot.png`
   to convert the /tmp/shot.xwd to ~/Desktop/shot.png (imagemagick is required)

Here is the screenshot of my login screen
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command...

```
unity-greeter --test-mode
```

... and taking a screenshot of that.

Comment: I need to capture my login screen which is with my username and background. and also the unity-greeter in the terminal is smaller.                                                          Thanks. more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have Written a small script to make it simple. I am sharing it here.

**Install Step 1:**
Save this code into your home directory a file named *loginsceenshot.sh*

```
## Save this file in your home folder loginscreenshot.sh 
## make the file Executable 
## Hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 
## login and run program using
## sudo ./loginscreenshot.sh
echo "Waiting  .... "
echo "Now Go to Ctrl+Alt+F7"
sleep 15
echo 'Click ...  '
DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/$DISPLAY xwd -root > tmp.xwd
convert tmp.xwd ScreenShot.png
rm tmp.xwd
echo "ScreenShot is Taken, Please check your home directory and open 'ScreenShot.png'"
```

**Install Step 2**
Hit Ctrl + Alt + F1, login, and type this.

```
chmod +x ./loginsceenshot.sh
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

**Use Step 1**
Hit Ctrl + Alt + F1, login, and type this.

```
sudo ./loginsceenshot.sh
```

**Use Step 2**
Hit Ctrl + Alt + F7, goto Login page and wait for 15 sec.

**Use Step 3** 
Open you home directory and look of ScreenShot.png

[image: Myhomescreen]