# How to move the logo on the login screen? GDM Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: logo

I recently changed the logo on the login screen (as you can see on the picture) but it's too large and we can't see it properly.

I just want to move it to the top to see it!

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Sorry for the low quality..

[image: Image from my lgin screen]

Comment: Please follow the procedure in http://askubuntu.com/questions/43458/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-login-screen to get a better picture. Are you sure that's not part of the wallpaper?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! No before it was a text "Ubunto 15.10", as << logo.png >>! Then I replaced it by this picture...

Comment: hello, i have the exact same issue with 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Quality should be better ! I hope you'll understand what i want to do

[image]