# Capture screenshot of login screen in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gdm, screenshot

How can I capture a screenshot of the login screen (GDM) in Ubuntu 17.10?

Previous answers to questions such as [How can I take a screenshot of the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43458/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-login-screen) do not apply to Ubuntu 17.10 because it uses Wayland by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I take a screenshot of the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43458/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-login-screen)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/43458/402324

Comment: @SouravGhosh you links are helpful but 17.10 is actually in the long row of Ubuntu versions an Unicorn, since it uses wayland by default which complicates things I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified in my question: those answers indeed don't work on 17.10 because of Wayland.

Comment: It might work if you force gdm log-screen to be X based btw. If you want i can write an answer bout that.

Comment: @Videonauth, sure, although I prefer a solution that works with wayland.