# How to take a screenshot of the login screen on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: login, screenshot

I followed [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/screenshot-login-screen-ubuntu-linux) on how to take a screenshot for the login screen.

However in Ubuntu 20.04 it doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
xwd: unable to open open display ':0'
```

Below is the script I'm using (extracted from the guide with a modified `chvt`)

```bsh
chvt 1;
sleep 5s;
DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/lib/gdm/:0 xwd -root -out ~/screenshot.xwd;
convert ~/screenshot.xwd ~/screenshot.png;
rm ~/screenshot.xwd
```

Comment: I only have gdm in a 20.10 install but it would be login screen > vt3 > login > chvt 7 >  goes back to login screen

Comment: Seems not. `chvt 7` goes to some weird version of the command line login screen. I have to use `chvt 1` and also `Ctrl + Alt + F1` goes to the login screen and not `Ctrl + Alt + F7`

Comment: I'd just use a virtual machine if I needed a screenshot of the login screen. It's not fancy, but it works. There are also a ton of ways to try [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43458/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-login-screen).

Comment: My machine is not powerful enough to run a VM, it brings my computer to a halt. I already tried the suggestions in that post, but I can't find any that work for 20.04, even the one at the bottom that says it  works on 20.04

Comment: Did you try this one?? https://askubuntu.com/a/1237166/739431